# I have one array and i want to find the index of biggest number and display the index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

i have used this `array` and `function` to find the biggest number:

```
$nums=array(9,3,1,0,99,2,5,6,32,1,55);

function big($big) {
    echo "The highest value is: ";
    echo max($big);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, just use `array_search();` and then you can use `max();` again:

```
<?php

    $nums = array(9, 3, 1, 0, 99, 2, 5, 6, 32, 1, 55, 11);

    echo "The highest key is: ";
    echo array_search(max($nums), $nums);
    echo "<br />";


?>
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Its giving me 10, which is the total number of elements int the array.but i want index of highest number

Comment: @ArchitBhatia Did you used my entire code i posted? an you got 10?

Comment: @ArchitBhatia Sorry misunderstood your question first and updated it now! So it should work!